# Jquery Sliding images on ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am working on website which includes lot of images. I decided to use jquery.i refer to this code [Here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/09/28/polaroid-photobar-gallery/).

In this it shows album of images when you click on album it shows all images thumbnail.clicking on thumbnail it shows large view of that image. It works fine in html page. When i used in .aspx page as I click on album image thumbnail it not showing large preview. It shows text under image. All path are correct.

After so many tries I found that it not working in chrome browser in office but same code i tried in home it works in chrome.

**My Code is **

```
    <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Collection.aspx.vb" Inherits="Collection" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
        <title>Polaroid Photobar Gallery with jQuery</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="description" content="Polaroid Photobar Gallery" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="polaroid, jquery, css3, rotation, image gallery"/>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/Note_this_400.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Cufon.replace('span');
            Cufon.replace('h1', {
                textShadow: '0px 1px #ddd'
            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            h1{
                font-size:50px;
                margin:50px;
                color:#333;
            }
            span.reference{
                font-family:Arial;
                position:fixed;
                right:10px;
                top:10px;
                font-size:15px;
            }
            span.reference a{
                color:#fff;
                text-transform:uppercase;
                text-decoration:none;
            }
        </style>


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    <h1>Polaroid Photobar Gallery</h1>
        <div id="pp_gallery">

            <div id="pp_loading" class="pp_loading"></div>
            <div id="pp_next" class="pp_next"></div>
            <div id="pp_prev" class="pp_prev"></div>
            <div id="pp_thumbContainer">

                <div class="album">
                    <div class="content">
                        <img src="images/album1/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="images/album1/1.jpg" />
                        <span>The Sixties by Tetsumo</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <img src="images/album1/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="images/album1/2.jpg" />
                        <span>The Sixties by Tetsumo</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <img src="images/album1/thumbs/3.jpg" alt="images/album1/3.jpg" />
                        <span>The Sixties by Tetsumo</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <img src="images/album1/thumbs/4.jpg" alt="images/album1/4.jpg" />
                        <span>The Sixties by Tetsumo</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <img src="images/album1/thumbs/5.jpg" alt="images/album1/5.jpg" />
                        <span>The Sixties by Tetsumo</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <img src="images/album1/thumbs/6.jpg" alt="images/album1/6.jpg" />
                        <span>The Sixties by Tetsumo</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="descr">
                        The Sixties
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="album">
                    <div class="content">
                        <img src="images/album2/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="images/album2/1.jpg" />
                        <span>Butterfly Girl</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <img src="images/album2/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="images/album2/2.jpg" />
                        <span>Mmmmmmh Strawberries</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <img src="images/album2/thumbs/3.jpg" alt="images/album2/3.jpg" />
                        <span>Polaroid in Picture</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <img src="images/album2/thumbs/4.jpg" alt="images/album2/4.jpg" />
                        <span>Girl with brown hair</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <img src="images/album2/thumbs/5.jpg" alt="images/album2/5.jpg" />
                        <span>Hair up</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <img src="images/album2/thumbs/6.jpg" alt="images/album2/6.jpg" />
                        <span>Smiling Girl</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="descr">
                        Portraits
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="pp_back" class="pp_back">Albums</div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!-- The JavaScript -->
        <script src="js/jquery.transform-0.8.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                var ie          = false;
                if ($.browser.msie) {
                    ie = true;
                }
                //current album/image displayed 
                var enableshow  = true;
                var current     = -1;
                var album       = -1;
                //windows width
                var w_width     = $(window).width();
                //caching
                var $albums     = $('#pp_thumbContainer div.album');
                var $loader     = $('#pp_loading');
                var $next       = $('#pp_next');
                var $prev       = $('#pp_prev');
                var $images     = $('#pp_thumbContainer div.content img');
                var $back       = $('#pp_back');

                //we wnat to spread the albums through the page equally
                //number of spaces to divide with:number of albums plus 1
                var nmb_albums  = $albums.length;
                var spaces      = w_width/(nmb_albums+1);
                var cnt         = 0;
                //preload all the images (thumbs)
                var nmb_images  = $images.length;
                var loaded      = 0;
                $images.each(function(i){
                    var $image = $(this);
                    $('<img />').load(function(){
                        ++loaded;
                        if(loaded == nmb_images){
                            //let's spread the albums equally on the bottom of the page
                            $albums.each(function(){
                                var $this   = $(this);
                                ++cnt;
                                var left    = spaces*cnt - $this.width()/2;
                                $this.css('left',left+'px');
                                $this.stop().animate({'bottom':'0px'},500);
                            }).unbind('click').bind('click',spreadPictures);
                            //also rotate each picture of an album with a random number of degrees
                            $images.each(function(){
                                var $this   = $(this);
                                var r       = Math.floor(Math.random()*41)-20;
                                $this.transform({'rotate'   : r + 'deg'});
                            });
                        }
                    }).attr('src', $image.attr('src'));
                });

                function spreadPictures(){
                    var $album  = $(this);
                    //track which album is opened
                    album       = $album.index();
                    //hide all the other albums
                    $albums.not($album).stop().animate({'bottom':'-90px'},300);
                    $album.unbind('click');
                    //now move the current album to the left 
                    //and at the same time spread its images through 
                    //the window, rotating them randomly. Also hide the description of the album

                    //store the current left for the reverse operation
                    $album.data('left',$album.css('left'))
                          .stop()
                          .animate({'left':'0px'},500).find('.descr').stop().animate({'bottom':'-30px'},200);
                    var total_pic   = $album.find('.content').length;
                    var cnt         = 0;
                    //each picture
                    $album.find('.content')
                          .each(function(){
                        var $content = $(this);
                        ++cnt;
                        //window width
                        var w_width     = $(window).width();
                        var spaces      = w_width/(total_pic+1);
                        var left        = (spaces*cnt) - (140/2);
                        var r           = Math.floor(Math.random()*41)-20;
                        //var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*81)-40;
                        $content.stop().animate({'left':left+'px'},500,function(){
                            $(this).unbind('click')
                                   .bind('click',showImage)
                                   .unbind('mouseenter')
                                   .bind('mouseenter',upImage)
                                   .unbind('mouseleave')
                                   .bind('mouseleave',downImage);
                        }).find('img')
                          .stop()
                          .animate({'rotate': r+'deg'},300);
                        $back.stop().animate({'left':'0px'},300);
                    });
                }

                //back to albums
                //the current album gets its innitial left position
                //all the other albums slide up
                //the current image slides out
                $back.bind('click',function(){
                    $back.stop().animate({'left':'-100px'},300);
                    hideNavigation();
                    //there's a picture being displayed
                    //lets slide the current one up
                    if(current != -1){
                        hideCurrentPicture();
                    }

                    var $current_album = $('#pp_thumbContainer div.album:nth-child('+parseInt(album+1)+')');
                    $current_album.stop()
                                  .animate({'left':$current_album.data('left')},500)
                                  .find('.descr')
                                  .stop()
                                  .animate({'bottom':'0px'},500);

                    $current_album.unbind('click')
                                  .bind('click',spreadPictures);

                    $current_album.find('.content')
                              .each(function(){
                                var $content = $(this);
                                $content.unbind('mouseenter mouseleave click');
                                $content.stop().animate({'left':'0px'},500);
                                });

                    $albums.not($current_album).stop().animate({'bottom':'0px'},500);
                });

                //displays an image (clicked thumb) in the center of the page
                //if nav is passed, then displays the next / previous one of the 
                //current album
                function showImage(nav){
                    if(!enableshow) return;
                    enableshow = false;
                    if(nav == 1){
                        //reached the first one
                        if(current==0){
                            enableshow = true;
                            return;
                        }
                        var $content            = $('#pp_thumbContainer div.album:nth-child('+parseInt(album+1)+')')
                                                  .find('.content:nth-child('+parseInt(current)+')');
                        //reached the last one
                        if($content.length==0){
                            enableshow = true;
                            current-=2;
                            return;
                        }   
                    }
                    else
                        var $content            = $(this);

                    //show ajax loading image
                    $loader.show();

                    //there's a picture being displayed
                    //lets slide the current one up
                    if(current != -1){
                        hideCurrentPicture();
                    }

                    current                 = $content.index();
                    var $thumb              = $content.find('img');
                    var imgL_source         = $thumb.attr('alt');
                    var imgL_description    = $thumb.next().html();
                    //preload the large image to show
                    $('<img style=""/>').load(function(){
                        var $imgL   = $(this);
                        //resize the image based on the windows size
                        resize($imgL);
                        //create an element to include the large image
                        //and its description
                        var $preview = $('<div />',{
                            'id'        : 'pp_preview',
                            'className' : 'pp_preview',
                            'html'      : '<div class="pp_descr"><span>'+imgL_description+'</span></div>',
                            'style'     : 'visibility:hidden;'
                        });
                        $preview.prepend($imgL);
                        $('#pp_gallery').prepend($preview);

                        var largeW              = $imgL.width()+20;
                        var largeH              = $imgL.height()+10+45;
                        //change the properties of the wrapping div 
                        //to fit the large image sizes
                        $preview.css({
                            'width'         :largeW+'px',
                            'height'        :largeH+'px',
                            'marginTop'     :-largeH/2-20+'px',
                            'marginLeft'    :-largeW/2+'px',
                            'visibility'    :'visible'
                        });
                        Cufon.replace('.pp_descr');
                        //show navigation
                        showNavigation();

                        //hide the ajax image loading
                        $loader.hide();

                        //slide up (also rotating) the large image
                        var r           = Math.floor(Math.random()*41)-20;
                        if(ie)
                            var param = {
                                'top':'50%'
                            };
                        else
                            var param = {
                                'top':'50%',
                                'rotate': r+'deg'
                            };
                        $preview.stop().animate(param,500,function(){
                            enableshow = true;
                        });
                    }).error(function(){
                        //error loading image. Maybe show a message : 'no preview available'?
                    }).attr('src',imgL_source); 
                }

                //click next image
                $next.bind('click',function(){
                    current+=2;
                    showImage(1);
                });

                //click previous image
                $prev.bind('click',function(){
                    showImage(1);
                });

                //slides up the current picture
                function hideCurrentPicture(){
                    current = -1;
                    var r   = Math.floor(Math.random()*41)-20;
                    if(ie)
                        var param = {
                            'top':'-150%'
                        };
                    else
                        var param = {
                            'top':'-150%',
                            'rotate': r+'deg'
                        };
                    $('#pp_preview').stop()
                                    .animate(param,500,function(){
                                        $(this).remove();
                                    });
                }

                //shows the navigation buttons
                function showNavigation(){
                    $next.stop().animate({'right':'0px'},100);
                    $prev.stop().animate({'left':'0px'},100);
                }

                //hides the navigation buttons
                function hideNavigation(){
                    $next.stop().animate({'right':'-40px'},300);
                    $prev.stop().animate({'left':'-40px'},300);
                }

                //mouseenter event on each thumb
                function upImage(){
                    var $content    = $(this);
                    $content.stop().animate({
                        'marginTop'     : '-70px'
                    },400).find('img')
                          .stop()
                          .animate({'rotate': '0deg'},400);
                }

                //mouseleave event on each thumb
                function downImage(){
                    var $content    = $(this);
                    var r           = Math.floor(Math.random()*41)-20;
                    $content.stop().animate({
                        'marginTop'     : '0px'
                    },400).find('img').stop().animate({'rotate': r + 'deg'},400);
                }

                //resize function based on windows size
                function resize($image){
                    var widthMargin     = 50
                    var heightMargin    = 200;

                    var windowH      = $(window).height()-heightMargin;
                    var windowW      = $(window).width()-widthMargin;
                    var theImage     = new Image();
                    theImage.src     = $image.attr("src");
                    var imgwidth     = theImage.width;
                    var imgheight    = theImage.height;

                    if((imgwidth > windowW)||(imgheight > windowH)){
                        if(imgwidth > imgheight){
                            var newwidth = windowW;
                            var ratio = imgwidth / windowW;
                            var newheight = imgheight / ratio;
                            theImage.height = newheight;
                            theImage.width= newwidth;
                            if(newheight>windowH){
                                var newnewheight = windowH;
                                var newratio = newheight/windowH;
                                var newnewwidth =newwidth/newratio;
                                theImage.width = newnewwidth;
                                theImage.height= newnewheight;
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            var newheight = windowH;
                            var ratio = imgheight / windowH;
                            var newwidth = imgwidth / ratio;
                            theImage.height = newheight;
                            theImage.width= newwidth;
                            if(newwidth>windowW){
                                var newnewwidth = windowW;
                                var newratio = newwidth/windowW;
                                var newnewheight =newheight/newratio;
                                theImage.height = newnewheight;
                                theImage.width= newnewwidth;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $image.css({'width':theImage.width+'px','height':theImage.height+'px'});
                }
            });
        </script>


    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Anyone Plz help! i am stuck!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are running this on visual studio IIS Express/development server that is part of VS , I had the same issue with this, just setup your project as LOCAL IIS website rather than FileSystem website on Visual studio. create a iis VIRTUAL DIRECTORY APPLICATION ON IIS and it should work fine.